# Worst Case Hash Function

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

Something was mentioned in class along the lines of "the worst case hash function, h(x) = 1"

(My instructor is out of town for a couple weeks; I obviously would just ask him if I could).

My question: What exactly is meant by the "worst case hash function"? Is it such that each element is given the same value of 1 (or 1 % tableSize), or such that elementOne is given a hash value of 1, elementTwo 2, elementThree 3, and so on?

Probably a noob question, but I thought I'd ask it anyhow.

Comment: It is conceptually similar to the worst [random number generator](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 6):

A quality of hash functions is determined by the probability of getting a collision with multiple distinct objects. A perfect hash function maps all objects to numbers with no collisions at all, guaranteeing an even spread of items among buckets.

In contrast, the worst possible hash function guarantees a collision by returning the same value for all objects, regardless of what object you pass. This transforms hash-based lookup into collision resolution lookup, eliminating any advantages of using a hash-based container in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The worst hash function is one that returns a constant value. I.e. all objects of that type have the same hash value, resulting in tons of collisions.

While collisions can not usually be avoided entirely, minimising them is important for the performance of anything working with hashes.

It should be noted that while it is a terrible hash function, it is technically correct, since the requirement for a hash function is simply to return identical values for objects that are considered equal (which this trivially does, since it returns identical values for everything).

Answer (score 3):

In the worst case, every object has the same hash (e.g. 1). This is consistent with equals, to the extent that two equal objects will always have the same hash, so it will work; but it won't give you any of the lookup benefits that a good hash gives, because every time you try and look up an object, you have to look through every object in your collection (because they all have the same hash).

Answer (score 0):

The worst hash function is a function that returns a constant value.
In a collection based on the hash, the objects are stored according to their hash value.
So, if for any object you get the same hash value, it means that all objects are finally stored in the same place.
So, the collection needs to **iterate** always and **always** the same the bucket/slot associated to this hash value to retrieve the object.

You lose the interest to use a hash function.

Answer (score 0):

The hash function which you have defined `h(x)=1` generates the same value for no matter what x is. An ideal hash function would be generating a unique key for every value of x. The constant hash function will end up generating same hash value for every value of x. So if you take the case of hash table it would be a single element table with a huge linked list